# I am trying to alter the user password through a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to alter the user password through a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @newpwd VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @usrid VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @oldpass VARCHAR(50)

SET @usrid = 'ddladmin'
SET @newpwd = 'demo@121245'
SET @oldpass = 'demo@123'

SET @SQL = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @usrid + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@newpwd, '''') + ' OLD_PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@oldpass, '''');

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

With the above query I'm getting an error:

> Cannot alter the login 'ddladmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

But when I try to alter it directly through `alter` script, e.g.

```
ALTER LOGIN ddladmin WITH PASSWORD ='demo@12121'
```

it is working. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is the reason for altering this through a process? Automate the changing passwords over time? Should your database connections change that often? Who gives authoriZation for altering passwords?

Comment: Actually we are trying to automate t increase the security.. We plan to schedule the job ..

Comment: Wait...what? Schedule a job. Is this an application user and how are you enforcing industry standard passwords? Usually a password should involve some change process.

Comment: You are also asking a lot since whatever account this is running under would have to have a lot of power like securityadmin server role. Are we sure we understand the security hole that firing off plain text passwords inside your database does? You may say this enhances security, but the code looks like it invites a worse security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear:

> because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I have tried to run your script and it worked without any error for me.

So assuming that the login `ddladmin` exists on your server, it means that **you do not have permissions to change the login**. You should check under which user you are running the query and eventually [change the execution context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql):

```
SELECT USER_NAME(), SUSER_NAME()
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL    
EXECUTE AS LOGIN ='SA'    
SELECT USER_NAME(), SUSER_NAME()    
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL    
REVERT
```